# How to flatten a dictionary with nested sequences into a single sequence with all values and keys?

Tags: python

I have a workable solution that returns a set:

```
>>> a = {'a': {'1', '2', '3'}, 'b': {'4', '5', '6'}, 'c': {'7', '8', '9'}}

>>> def flatten_nested(a):
        temp = set(
            [value for value_set in a.values() for value in value_set]
        )
        return temp | a.keys()

>>> flatten_nested(a)
>>> {'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c'}
```

I wondered if there was some `itertools.chain`-like function already built in to Python to do something similar?

Comment: @wim,  they are probably using python3 where .keys is a dictview object so there is no need for the set call although `return temp.union(a)` would work for both python2 and 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess more simple is this:

```
>>> set.union(set(a), *a.values())
{'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c'}
```

Or, here's the same thing via the bound method:

```
>>> set(a).union(*a.values())
{'1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'a', 'b', 'c'}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the values are already sets then [wims answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38731658/2141635) is the simplest, but to work for iterables like a list, tuples etc.. you would have to map to a set i.e `set(a).union(map(set, a.values())` or you could union the [chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) of all the values with the view of the keys:

```
from itertools import chain
def flatten_nested(a):
    return a.keys() | chain(*a.values()) # a.viewkeys() python2
```

Comment: Fun fact, the dict_keys view supports the operand `|` with a chain object, but an actual set doesn't!